# PHP resized image functions and S3 upload functions - but how to merge the two?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using S3 to store images and I am resizing and compressing images before it gets uploaded using PHP.  I'm using this class for storing the images to an S3 bucket - http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

This all works fine if I'm not doing any file processing before the file is uploaded because it reads the file upload from the $_FILES array.

The problem is I am resizing and compressing the image before storing to the S3 bucket.  So I'm no longer able to read from the $_FILES array.

The functions for resizing:

```
            public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
        {
            // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
            $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

            $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


            // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


            // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
            if ($option == 'crop') {
                $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }
        }
```

The script I am using to store the file after resizing and compressing to a local directory:

```
            public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
        {
            // *** Get extension
            $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
            $extension = strtolower($extension);

            switch($extension)
            {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.jpeg':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                        imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.gif':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                        imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.png':
                    // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                    $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                    // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                    $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                         imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                // ... etc

                default:
                    // *** No extension - No save.
                    break;
            }

            imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
        }
```

with this PHP code to invoke it:

```
                $resizeObj = new resize("$images_dir/$filename");                   
                $resizeObj -> resizeImage($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, 'crop');                 
                $resizeObj -> saveImage($images_dir."/tb_".$filename, 90);
```

How do I modify the code above so I can pass it through this function:

```
$s3->putObjectFile($thefile, "s3bucket", $s3directory, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the copy PHP function to save to a temporary directory and then used the S3 function to read from the directory.  Once the S3 upload is complete, the file is deleted from the temporary directory using the unlink function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you meant with the `$_FILES` variable. If you move the uploaded file to a local path after editing it, `$_FILES` will no longer be of any use for you.

From what I understand from the question, I would make a new function `putImageToServer`:

```
public function putImageToServer($path, $imageQuality) {
    saveImage($path, $imageQuality);
    $s3->putObjectFile($path, "s3bucket", $s3directory, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)

    // Now, if you don't want the file to be on your local directory,
    unlink($path);
}
```

However, you should either make `$s3directory` a constant or an instance variable so that the new method could use that variable.

I'm sorry if this is not the answer you're looking for, I've tried to answer it based on what I understood from the question.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just to clarify then. When you upload from a form it stores the upload in a $_FILES system variable which I then use to assign to a local variable for resizing and compressing via PHP.  The function I've listed in my original post is doing the resizing/compress then saving the file to a directory.  I don't want it to save to a directory, instead I want it to pass the file straight to the S3 bucket.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I save the finished file to my web server and then upload to S3 then delete the web-server image? I thought that might be a solution but it seemed like an extra unnecessary step?

Comment: Well, $_FILES variable stores the files in a temporary location. Since you are editing the image before sending it to the server, you should save it somewhere. I checked the PHP manual for imagepng, it only returns a boolean value. If that method had returned a temporary path to the image, then you could've directly used that. But that's not the case.

Comment: I've included the functions used for resizing in the original post.  Is there anyway to take the image file (which I assume is stored in memory at this point) and pass it as a variable to the S3 function?

Comment: This also depends on the Amazon S3 API. From the link you've given me, I've come to the conclusion that the first parameter of the `putObjectFile` (`$thefile` on the original post) needs to be the PATH to the file. Hence, I would suggest you save the file locally, then give the path of the file as the parameter and delete the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've now managed to get it working as per your suggestion.   I will continue to look for a more efficient way of doing this which allows me to do all of the image resizing processing in memory rather than saving the uploaded image first then opening from a directory, resizing, saving again, then upload to S3. Seems long winded and makes more sense to be able to work with the uploaded image from the tmp directory then upload to S3 directly. Or is it not possible to work with files in the tmp directory?

Comment: Hmm, good idea. I didn't think of that! Try using the `$_FILES` variable and get the `tmp_name` from the array. Resize the image by using the path from `tmp_name`, and set the `$savePath` variable to `tmp_name` variable. I'm not entirely sure, but this should get the image from `tmp_name` and save it back to `tmp_name`. However, be careful, when handling temporary files, you must use it like this: `$path = sys_get_temp_dir() . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`, this will return the path for the temporary file. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: I've given it a try and I get this error: S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: /tmp/tmp/phpxf639i

Comment: Is it because there's one too many 'tmp' in that path? Not sure how to remove it though?

Comment: when I do a print_r on the $_FILES array, the key of tmp_name specifies the temp directory (e.g. /tmp/randomcharacters). I have tried also constructing the full file path by connecting tmp_name and name values but this hasn't worked.

Comment: Yes - I've read about it and figured that out now. Can you confirm that you were able to resize the image properly with the `tmp_file` value? If yes, then maybe that Amazon S3 API requires files to end with an extension (which in your case, doesn't end with an extension). Unfortunately, this is all I can think of. The method I suggested may be the most efficient way **unless** 1) you can find an `imagepng()` method that returns a resource instead of bool, and 2) the Amazon S3 API can accept resource (which I believe is `S3::imageResource()`).

Comment: When resizing and saving back to the tmp folder, all I get is a blank image.  The file name extensions are being specified correctly, I've checked this by echoing the path and file variables. I may have to revisit this another time. For now I will take a look at using php to delete the file saved to the web server after its successfully uploaded to S3.  Thanks for your help.